# Mysql представление с возможностью получения значений с самого себя

Tags: mysql

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в создании представлений...

Есть табличка с числами на каждый день:

```
+------------+-------+
|    date    | value | 
+------------+-------+
| 2018-02-10 |   5   |      
| 2018-02-11 |   2   |    
| 2018-02-12 |   3   |
| 2018-02-13 |   1   |
| 2018-02-14 |   7   | 
+------------+-------+
```

Есть в другой табличке начальное значение: 100.

Нужно представление, которое будет считать остаток.

Пример. 2018-02-09 было 100шт товара. каждый день идёт списание.

Представление должно показывать остаток на каждый день.

В итоге получить:

```
+------------+-------+
|    date    |  rest | 
+------------+-------+
| 2018-02-10 |   95  |      
| 2018-02-11 |   93  |    
| 2018-02-12 |   90  |
| 2018-02-13 |   89  |
| 2018-02-14 |   82  | 
+------------+-------+
```

Как я понял, для первой строки нужно сделать разницу поля "Начальное количество" и первого дня, а для остальных делать разницу того что получилось в представлении в предыдущей строке и убытка за день.

Вот начало запроса который удалось написать:

```
select `ks`.`Date` AS `Date`,if((`ks`.`Id` = '1'),(`hc`.`HС` - `ks`.`HC`),'0') AS `HC` from ((`CS`.`KH` `ks` join `CS`.`Users` `hc`) where (`hc`.`TableName` = 'K')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С запросом - так:

```
SELECT t.`date`, t.value, @amount:=@amount-t.value rest
FROM `table` t, (SELECT @amount:=100) dummy
ORDER BY t.`date` ASC;
```

С представлением - так:

```
CREATE VIEW GetReminder
AS
SELECT t1.`date`, t1.value, 100-SUM(t2.value) rest
FROM `table` t1, `table` t2
WHERE t1.`date` >= t2.`date`
GROUP BY t1.`date`;

SELECT * FROM GetReminder;
```

Comment: Почему-то запрос: SET (собака не вставляется в комментарий)amount:=100; в представлении выводит ошибку -  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set (собака не вставляется в комментарий)amount:=100' at line 7. Если сделать просто запрос, то выполняется...
A view definition is subject to the following restrictions:
The SELECT statement cannot contain a subquery in the FROM 
clause.
The SELECT statement cannot refer to system or user variables. Такое в документации(

Comment: Ок, исправил. Проверил, работает.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Заработало:) Как вы думаете, это представление нагрузит базу, если дней будет 600?:)

Comment: Не знаю, надо тестировать. Хотя с моей точки зрения 360 тыс. записей в объединении - не так уж и много. Другое дело, что я навылет не понимаю, зачем потребовалось именно представление - для поставленной задачи оно совершенно бессмысленно.

Comment: Просто данные убытка могут меняться, а в итоге нужна табличка остатка в день. Если хранить просто остаток, который считается каждый день, то при редактировании убытка в какой-то прошлый день придется пересчитывать остаток начиная с этой даты и дальше, подумал представление автоматом проще это сделает, чем нужно будет вызывать процедуру пересчёта например:)

Comment: Процедура как раз проще. Ей можно передавать параметры - начало периода, конец периода, баланс на начало...